# Where is the missing space of a new EXT4 partition?

Tags: partitioning

I have a ext4 partition of 8TB as the following pictures shows (from df):

```
Filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdf1   7.2T  179M  6.8T   1%   /mnt
```

Some information from that partition:

```
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          bd72ba0e-1cb5-4444-98e4-826907ebaed5
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              488382464
Block count:              1953506048
Reserved block count:     97675302
Free blocks:              1922806561
Free inodes:              488382453
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      558
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
```

I have some questions:

1. What is the 179MB used space for?
2. It is obvious that available space ≠ total space - used space, why?
3. Does reserved block include the blocks that store inode?
4. Why the `Use%` is 1% ? if 1%, the used space should be about 72G.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why post text as a picture, and not copy paste it?

Comment: I think `1%` is the smallest unit which can be displayed in the `Use%`-column. The real value is less and what you see is rounded up.

Comment: The used space is for metadata. Every file system needs some structures to store information about the files

Comment: Also in Linux the default is to reserve 5% of the diskspace for the superuser (this can be adjusted using tune2fs -m).
`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdXY` where sdX is drive & Y is partition  The old 5% was the standard with much smaller drives. If just data drive or you are good about monitoring use, you can adjust to smaller percentage.